# How to check if a service is installed and to start the service if installed else if install and start a service in chef for windows

Tags: chef-infra, action

How to check if a service is installed and to start the service if installed else if install and start a service in chef for windows

```
if service "VigilEntAgent" 
 supports :status => false then 
 package 'VigilEntAgent' do
source 'xxx'
 action :install
end
else 
 service "VigilEntAgent" do
 action :start
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check, if the windows service installed with

```
::Win32::Service.exists?( '<service_name>' )
```

But if you use `package` resource to install service, most probably you just need to provide a right name for the `package` resource. The one you see in *Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features*. Chef will check it the package already installed and will not try to install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Chef is made to be idempotent, what you should do is:

```
package 'VigilEntAgent' do  
  source 'xxx'   
  action :install  
end   

windows_service "VigilEntAgent"   
  action :start
end
```

The service name has to match the service short name in windows service manager, the one you would use with `NET START` to start it from the command line IIRC.

The `windows_service` resource is available since chef 12.

Documentation of resources is here: https://docs.chef.io/resources.html

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't how Windows services tend to work, specifically the `status_command`. Services on Windows are much more involved than on Unix platforms.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did that in the past (for a nssm based service), but maybe this is still handled by an old client and include a hugly hack.